# How to download a file, modify it and upload it to Azure File Storage using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I have a file on Azure File Share and I would like to download it, modify it and then upload it again using Powershell. This is the code I have written so far and it is not working:

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$share = Get-AzStorageShare -Name $shareName -Context $context
$client = $share.CloudBlob.OpenRead($filePath)
$file = $client.DownloadText()
```

Unfortunately it gives me an error. What could be wrong with the code?

Comment: There is no way we can help you if you do not provide the error you are receiving

Comment: System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

Comment: @Olgaraa, please add this information directly to your question, don't use comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a file on Azure File Share like below:

[image]

Using Azure Automation modify the script and upload it you can make of below script like below.

```c
$Appid = "789da472-e33e-4de6-bada-XXXXXXX"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Yig8Q~_R_RPrl_Wrcn2CX5VAsngwR1tXXXXXXX" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenant = "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2dXXXXXXX"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Appid, $PWord

# Authenticate
$null = Add-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenant -ServicePrincipal

$storageAccountName = "xxxxx"
$storageAccountKey = "euf04t6rJW7z7UKr1VhSlfduHAlouTZ7/rxzzMhmOE7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

# File share information
$shareName = "file1"
$filePath = 'demo.txt'

try {
    # Construct the storage context
    $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

    # Define a temporary directory within the Azure Automation sandbox
    $tempPath = Join-Path $env:TEMP "tempfile1.txt" 

    Write-Output "Share Name: $shareName"
    Write-Output "Temporary Path: $tempPath"

    # Get the file content from the Azure File Share
    Write-Output "Getting file content from Azure File Share..."
    Get-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName $shareName -Path $filePath -Destination $tempPath -Context $context
    Write-Output "File content retrieved and saved to temporary directory."

    # Read and modify the file content
    $fileContent = Get-Content $tempPath
    Write-Output $fileContent
    $newFileContent = $fileContent -replace 'Imran123', 'Khan123'
    $newFileContent | Set-Content $tempPath
    Write-Output $newFileContent

    Set-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName $shareName -Source $tempPath -Path $filePath -Context $context -Force
    Write-Output "Modified file content uploaded."
}
catch {
    Write-Output "An error occurred: $_"
}

# Sign out to avoid potential issues with credentials
Remove-AzAccount -Scope Process
```

Now when I ran the above script, file is modified and uploaded in file share successfully like below:

[image]

***Output***:

[image]